# UIImageView passing (segue) nil to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, segue

after a day of researching and trying stuff, I come to your aid.

I have a collectionView passing an image to an imageView, just like instagram (for you to imagine the interface), I THINK I'm performing the segue right, but on the other viewController it ends up NIL.

My code is as follows:

First View Controller >

```
    //  TakePhotoViewController.swift

    import UIKit
    import Photos

    class TakePhotoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


    var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        grabPhotos()
    }

    @IBAction func postPhotoTaken(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "photoPost", sender: self)
    }


    func grabPhotos(){

        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()

        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

        if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {image, error in

                        self.imageArray.append(image!)

                    })
                }
            }

            else {
                print("You Don't Have Any Photos!")
            }
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

        imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        photoImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1

        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "photoPost" {

            let photoPost = segue.destination as! PhotoPostTableViewController

            let imagePhoto = self.photoImageView.image
            photoPost.photo = imagePhoto!
        }
    }

}
```

Second View Controller >

```
//  photoPostViewController.swift

import UIKit

class PhotoPostTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var photo: UIImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var newPhoto: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        newPhoto.image = photo
        print(photo)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        newPhoto.image = photo
        print(photo)
    }

}
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: If you break on let imagePhoto = self.photoImageView.image, what is the value of self.photoImageView.image? Does that line get called at all?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Swift programming, I added the breakpoint, but it seems it's not being called at all. I even wrote a print below that line and added a breakpoint but nothing comes up on the console.

Comment: Put following line before `if segue.identifier == "photoPost" {` : `print(">>> \(segue.identifier)")` to find out what is the identifier of the segue that gets performed - then you can change the condition to that new code

Comment: Is your segue identifier actually "photoPost"?

Comment: in `postPhotoTaken()` he's trying to perform that segue, so I guess he has something wired up incorrectly

Comment: It prints >>> nil

Comment: Go to your storyboard and change the identifier for your segue to the next controller.

Comment: that means the segue is triggered by the storyboards, not by the `postPhotoTaken(_ sender: Any)`, you must have wired up a segue on the button click.. check the storyboard, and find the segue that goes from first VC to second VC and is triggered by the button, and change it's identifier to "photoPost". and I believe you can delete `postPhotoTaken()`

Comment: Pet peeve, but it really caught my eye. You aren't *really* trying to pass a `UIImageView`. Even your code suggests that. It's a `UIImage`.

Comment: Thanks gents. Actually I was assigning the identifier in the wrong place hahaha Sorry to waste your time, but thank you very much! I was going crazy with this thing for hours hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the `segue.identifier` in your `prepare(for:)` returns nil, that means the segue performed is triggered by the storyboards, not by the `postPhotoTaken(_ sender: Any)`.

Check the storyboard, and find the segue that goes from first VC to second VC and is triggered by the button, and change it's `identifier` to `"photoPost"`.

I believe after that you can delete `postPhotoTaken(_ sender: Any)`.